# Strange behavior about 'to_json' filter in ansible

Tags: ansible

See example:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    a: "stackoverflow"
  tasks:
  - name: "print a"
    debug:
      msg: "-d '{{a|to_json}}' -s '{{a|to_json}}'"
```

**Expect output:**

```
"msg": "-d '\"stackoverflow\"' -s '\"stackoverflow\"'"
```

**In fact**

```
"msg": "-d '\"stackoverflow\" -s \"stackoverflow\"'"
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using? I'm using 2.9.18, and the output of your playbook is `"msg": "-d '\"stackoverflow\"' -s '\"stackoverflow\"'"`, which matches your expected output.

Comment: I am using ansible 2.9.11.

Comment: Try upgrading and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: Yeah, I upgraded, and it does.

Answer (score 1):

At ansible 2.9.11, result isn't incorrect. When i upgraded to 2.9.18, it was fine. Thank to @larsks.

Answer (score -1):

(ansible 2.9.6)

Make sure what callback plugin you use, e.g.

```sh
shell> ansible-config dump | grep DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK
DEFAULT_STDOUT_CALLBACK(/scratch/tmp/ansible.cfg) = yaml
```

The format of the output depends on [ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-stdout-callback). See what callback plugins are available

```sh
ansible-doc -t callback -l
```

For example, running your playbook

```sh
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook pb.yml
```

gives

```yaml
    "msg": "-d '\"stackoverflow\"' -s '\"stackoverflow\"'"
```

When you change the plugin to *yaml*

```sh
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook pb.yml
```

the format will be simpler

```yaml
  msg: -d '"stackoverflow"' -s '"stackoverflow"'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The key to this question is that  **'** has been ignored.